# Zend:does action helper's init method passes variables to layout view?

Tags: php, zend-framework, layout, controller, helper

**PROBLEM:** I can't pass my variables to my custom layout from  action helper's init method.

I have this action helper "My_Action_Helper_Initializer":

```
class My_Action_Helper_Initializer extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract
{
 public function init()
 {
  $controller=$this->getActionController();
  //variable passed to controller's view
  $controller->view->flop="FLOOP!!";
  //variable passed to controller
  $controller->boom="BOOM!!";
 }
}
```

In my controller "IndexController":

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{ 
  public function indexAction()
  {
    //print the variable passed from action helper
    echo $this->boom;
  }
}
```

then in my "layout.phtml":

```
//print variable passed from action helper
echo $this->flop;
```

- So the "boom" variable echoed out by controller action is shown correctly.
- The "flop" variable (passed to my layout) is not shown.

  **QUESTION:** Why the variable passed to controller action is correctly output while the other one passed to the layout view is not?

Thanks

Luca

Comment: echo $this->boom; in layout script?

Comment: My mistake it was $this->flop thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your helper's init() called, ViewRenderer's init() wasn't yet. This is because of order in helpers stack.

If you enable strict standards error reporting, you should see something like this in your helper "Creating default object from empty value in ..."

You should consider moving your code to preDispatch() hook as init() method should be used for **helper** initialization.

To get view instance for controller:

```
function getView()
{
    $controller = $this->getActionController();
    if($view = $controller->view) {
        return $view;
    }

    if($this->getFrontController()->getParam('noViewRenderer') {
        return $controller->initView();//this view instance will not be used in Zend_Layout!
    }
    $vr = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('viewRenderer');
    return $vr->initView();      

}
```

if you want to pass parameter to layout, then use

```
$view = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('viewRenderer')->initView();
```

Comment: "When your helper's init() called, ViewRenderer's init() wasn't yet..You should consider moving your code to preDispatch()".You mean that If I use a predispatch()for my action helper instead.. the ViewRenderer's init would be already called??

Comment: @luca yes, but only if noViewRender = true was not set as front controller parameter. ps: check updated code. Removed part not belonged there.

Comment: @Xerkus doesnt predispatch run first than init? I dont understand sorry! i thought the problem was that when the action helper is setting the view variable the view itself was already set..so by anticipating the code of my action helper with predispatch everything works..

Comment: I also tried with positioning the _initActionHelpers before of the _initView in my bootstrap and the init() method of my action Helper works again!..

Comment: action helpers init() called in constructor of Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker. Look at string 132 in Zend_Controller_Action. This is point, where it starts.

Comment: @luca there are 2 different preDispatch() hooks. One for front controller plugins and one for action helpers. Zend_Controller_Action's dispatch() method have `$this->_helper->notifyPreDispatch();` at line 500

Answer (score 2):

Action helpers are called so because they are a way to avoid code duplication in actions. Everything you do in an action helper is available to the actions but not to the view. That's the normal behaviour of actions, as long as you don't pass something to the view, the view doesn't know it. If you want to avoid code duplication in your views, create view helpers.

Sometimes it can make sense to create an action helper and a corresponding view helper.

--

preDispatch works() while init() doesn't because with init you're not actually hooking into the dispatch process.

Comment: I edited my question floop is passed to the layout..Gone for the view helper but I noticed that changing my 'init()' method for a 'predispatch' everything works..?why?

Comment: +1 for action helper and corresponding view helper. This approach is much better than figuring out where those damn view params come from few weeks later.